# Taking the code out of a view controller and moving it to a "Brain" that performs all functions Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have recently, after many errors, finished my first application (its a calculator) I learned that it is usually not wise to have any calculations be performed inside the ViewController but for it to instead be completed in a seperate file. My main question is:

**Is is possible to place my current code inside each of my functions into a class in swift that will perform them instead?**

Then I could just implement class.function() under each function in the view controller.

The reason why I want to do this is so for the future I can just have a calculator class, and I will also know how to do this with every future project and I will be able to use those classes as well.

I have tried experimenting but i cannot seem to reference the lbl.output in my other files.

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  MyCalculator
//
//  Created by Kevin Maldjian on 2/6/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 Kevin Maldjian. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import Foundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var num1 = ""
    var num2 = ""
    var finalString = ""
    var isFirstNumber = true
    var safeToAdd = true
    var hasFinalString = false
    var isClear = true
    var hasDecimal = false
    var doubleChecker = 0
    var hasSecondDecimal = false

    @IBOutlet weak var LBLOutput: UILabel!

    @IBAction func btrNumberClick(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if isClear {
            LBLOutput.text = ""
            isClear = false
        }
        let currentText = LBLOutput.text!
        let textLabel = sender.titleLabel?.text
        if let text = textLabel {
            switch text {
            case "+", "x", "/", "-","%":
                if hasFinalString {
                    return
                }
                finalString = text
                isFirstNumber = false
                hasFinalString = true
                safeToAdd = true
                LBLOutput.text = "\(currentText) \(finalString) "
                break
            case "=":
                if !hasFinalString
                {break}
                isFirstNumber = true
                hasFinalString = false
                isClear = true
                var result = calculate()
                if result.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy:1)  == 0
                {
                    result = (result)
                }
                LBLOutput.text = "\(result)"
                num1 = "\(result)"
                safeToAdd = false
                hasSecondDecimal = false
                hasDecimal = false
                break
            case ".":
                if !safeToAdd{
                    num1 = ""
                    LBLOutput.text = ""
                    num1 = "\(num1)\(text)"
                    LBLOutput.text = LBLOutput.text! + num1
                    safeToAdd = true

                } else if isFirstNumber{
                    if hasDecimal
                    {break}
                    LBLOutput.text = ""
                    num1 = "\(num1)\(text)"
                    LBLOutput.text = LBLOutput.text! + num1
                    hasDecimal = true

                }else{
                    if hasSecondDecimal
                    {break}
                    num2 = "\(num2)\(text)"
                    LBLOutput.text = "\(currentText)\(text)"
                    hasSecondDecimal = true


                }
                break

            default:
                if !safeToAdd{
                    num1 = ""
                    LBLOutput.text = ""
                    num1 = "\(num1)\(text)"
                    LBLOutput.text = LBLOutput.text! + num1
                    safeToAdd = true

                } else if isFirstNumber{
                    LBLOutput.text = ""
                    num1 = "\(num1)\(text)"
                    LBLOutput.text = LBLOutput.text! + num1

                }else{ num2 = "\(num2)\(text)"
                    LBLOutput.text = "\(currentText)\(text)"


                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    func calculate() -> Double {
        let firstNumber = Double(num1)!
        let secondNumber = Double(num2)!
        num1 = ""
        num2 = ""
        isClear = false
        switch finalString {
        case "+":
            return firstNumber + secondNumber
        case "-":
            return firstNumber - secondNumber
        case "x":
            return firstNumber * secondNumber
        case "/":
            return firstNumber / secondNumber
        case "%":
            return (firstNumber * 100) / secondNumber
        default:
            return 0
        }
    }

    @IBAction func clearTheLabel(_ sender: Any) {
        num1 = ""
        num2 = ""
        LBLOutput.text = "0"
        isClear = true
    }

    @IBAction func goNegative(_ sender: Any){
        var negativeChecker = Double(num1)!
        if negativeChecker > 0
        {    num1 = ("-" + num1)
            LBLOutput.text = num1
        }else{
            negativeChecker = (-2 * negativeChecker) + negativeChecker
            num1 = String(negativeChecker)
            LBLOutput.text = String(negativeChecker)
        }
    }

    @IBAction func squareRoot(_ sender: Any) {
        let squareRootX = sqrt(Double(LBLOutput.text!)!)
        num1 = String(squareRootX)
        LBLOutput.text = String(squareRootX)
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want help with code you need to post relevant code actually causing you an issue and you need to clearly point out where the issue is happening and what the issues are.

Comment: Take a day (or more) and do some searching on these terms, listed in order of what you need to gain most understanding of: (1) MVC or Model-View-Controller, (2) OOP or Object Oriented Programming, (3) MVCE or Minimal Viable Complete Example, (4) Anything related to how Xcode, Cocoa [Touch], or Apple implements **all** of the above, (5) SO or how StackOverflow works. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Rather than trying to call `LBLOutput.text = x` from your "brain" class, just have the brain functions return the correct value of your calculation, and use your viewController to set that as the text in your labels.  *That* is the intended use for a viewController if you are following "MVC".

For example, if your `Brain` class has a function called `sum` you could set it up like so:

```
class func sum(x: Int, y: Int) -> Int {
    return x + y
}
```

and in your viewController you can just say `LBLOutput.text = "\(Brain.sum(x, y: y)"`

Comment: Would it be possible to instead just make LBLOutput a variable in the calculator class? Then pass the UILabel?

Comment: @MarcusEspoiata That's the wrong way to do this. Think of the fact that your calculator "brain" class should know nothing about any user interface. And it should be reusable by any view controller.