# Creating a class that does all of the functions of the viewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift

I am attempting to make my calculator function look more organized. I have decided to create a calculator class that does all of the functions. Currently this is not working, my only problem is that I make a new instance of a class every time a number is pressed, this happens because I dont know what number is going to be pressed next so I cannot define LBLOutput in my constructor until It is passed to me. Here are my two files

**The problem lies where I am calling the cb.functions. Currently they work but only one number can show up on the screen at a time due to the fact that a new class is declared every time.**

Is this a viable way of making the calculator? Do i need to just start from scratch?

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  MyCalculator
//
//  Created by Kevin Maldjian on 2/6/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 Kevin Maldjian. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import Foundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var LBLOutput: UILabel!
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    }





    @IBAction func btrNumberClick(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let cb = calculatorBrain(LBLOutput: LBLOutput , sender: sender)
        cb.btrNumberClick()

    }


    @IBAction func clearTheLabel(_ sender: Any) {
        let cb = calculatorBrain(LBLOutput: LBLOutput, sender: sender as! UIButton)
        cb.clearTheLabel()
    }

    @IBAction func goNegative(_ sender: Any){
        let cb = calculatorBrain(LBLOutput: LBLOutput, sender: sender as! UIButton)
        cb.goNegative()
}

    @IBAction func squareRoot(_ sender: Any) {
        let cb = calculatorBrain(LBLOutput: LBLOutput, sender: sender as! UIButton)

        cb.squareRoot()
}
}
```

THE MAIN FUNCTIONS ARE DONE HERE

```
//
//  calculatorBrain.swift
//  SalvageAttempt
//
//  Created by Kevin Maldjian on 3/13/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 Kevin Maldjian. All rights reserved.
//

import Foundation
import UIKit

class calculatorBrain
{
    var num1 = ""
    var num2 = ""
    var finalString = ""
    var isFirstNumber = true
    var safeToAdd = true
    var hasFinalString = false
    var isClear = true
    var hasDecimal = false
    var doubleChecker = 0
    var hasSecondDecimal = false
    var LBLOutput = UILabel()
    var sender = UIButton()

    init(LBLOutput : UILabel, sender : UIButton) {
        self.num1 = " "
        self.num2 = " "
        self.finalString = ""
        self.isFirstNumber = true
        self.safeToAdd = true
        self.hasFinalString = false
        self.isClear = true
        self.hasDecimal = false
        self.doubleChecker = 0
        self.hasSecondDecimal = false
        self.LBLOutput = LBLOutput
        self.sender = sender
    }


    func btrNumberClick() {
        if isClear {
            LBLOutput.text = ""
            isClear = false
        }
        let currentText = LBLOutput.text!
        let textLabel = sender.titleLabel?.text
        if let text = textLabel {
            switch text {
            case "+", "x", "/", "-","%":
                if hasFinalString {
                    return
                }
                finalString = text
                isFirstNumber = false
                hasFinalString = true
                safeToAdd = true
                LBLOutput.text = "\(currentText) \(finalString) "
                break
            case "=":
                if !hasFinalString
                {break}
                isFirstNumber = true
                hasFinalString = false
                isClear = true
                var result = calculate()
                if result.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy:1)  == 0
                {
                    result = (result)
                }
                LBLOutput.text = "\(result)"
                num1 = "\(result)"
                safeToAdd = false
                hasSecondDecimal = false
                hasDecimal = false
                break
            case ".":
                if !safeToAdd{
                    num1 = ""
                    LBLOutput.text = ""
                    num1 = "\(num1)\(text)"
                    LBLOutput.text = LBLOutput.text! + num1
                    safeToAdd = true

                } else if isFirstNumber{
                    if hasDecimal
                    {break}
                    LBLOutput.text = ""
                    num1 = "\(num1)\(text)"
                    LBLOutput.text = LBLOutput.text! + num1
                    hasDecimal = true

                }else{
                    if hasSecondDecimal
                    {break}
                    num2 = "\(num2)\(text)"
                    LBLOutput.text = "\(currentText)\(text)"
                    hasSecondDecimal = true


                }
                break

            default:
                if !safeToAdd{
                    num1 = ""
                    LBLOutput.text = ""
                    num1 = "\(num1)\(text)"
                    LBLOutput.text = LBLOutput.text! + num1
                    safeToAdd = true

                } else if isFirstNumber{
                    LBLOutput.text = ""
                    num1 = "\(num1)\(text)"
                    LBLOutput.text = LBLOutput.text! + num1

                }else{ num2 = "\(num2)\(text)"
                    LBLOutput.text = "\(currentText)\(text)"


                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    func goNegative(){
        var negativeChecker = Double(num1)!
        if negativeChecker > 0
        {    num1 = ("-" + num1)
            LBLOutput.text = num1
        }else{
            negativeChecker = (-2 * negativeChecker) + negativeChecker
            num1 = String(negativeChecker)
            LBLOutput.text = String(negativeChecker)
        }
    }

    func squareRoot() {
        let squareRootX = sqrt(Double(LBLOutput.text!)!)
        num1 = String(squareRootX)
        LBLOutput.text = String(squareRootX)
    }


    @IBAction func clearTheLabel() {
        num1 = ""
        num2 = ""
        LBLOutput.text = "0"
        isClear = true
    }




    func calculate() -> Double {
        let firstNumber = Double(self.num1)!
        let secondNumber = Double(self.num2)!
        num1 = ""
        num2 = ""
        self.isClear = false
        switch finalString {
        case "+":
            return firstNumber + secondNumber
        case "-":
            return firstNumber - secondNumber
        case "x":
            return firstNumber * secondNumber
        case "/":
            return firstNumber / secondNumber
        case "%":
            return (firstNumber * 100) / secondNumber
        default:
            return 0
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Start from scratch. Sorry to be blunt, but why are you wrapping functions like everything *calculatorBrain* (BTW, in Swift the preferred syntax for a class would be *CalculatorBrain* in a class. Just make a public Swift file containing these Public functions and have you *one* instance of a UIViewController use them. Now you have your *state*, your *functions* available, and eliminated your cruft. (Which BTW, is a good thing to avoid.)

Comment: Are you in the same class as the person from [this other quesiton](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42775581/taking-the-code-out-of-a-view-controller-and-moving-it-to-a-brain-that-perform)?

Answer (score 0):

Move all of your functions out of this class called "calculatorBrain". Just make them public, or in the case of a separate target (like a Framework) open. For instance:

```
class MyVC:UIViewController {
    let a:Float = 1.0
    let b:Float = 1.0
    let currentSum = sum(a,b)
    print(currentSum)  // displays 2.0
}
```

In a separate file:

```
public sum(var1:Float, var2:Float) {
    return var1+var2
}
```

Not much more to it. Again, remove everything from a class and you won't need an instance.